# When's the earliest i can access some Session data in global.asax?

Tags: asp.net, session, global-asax

i want to check if the Session contains some key/value data, in my global.asax. I'm not sure when the earliest possible time (and method name) is, to check this.

thanks :)

Comment: Related/sort of a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977285/set-session-variable-in-application-beginrequest

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I always believed `Application_AcquireRequestState` was the first event in Global.asax that could access the current session. It's definitely not `Application_BeginRequest`.

Comment: This does in fact make Session available in MVC3 and 4 and IIS7 and 8, IF the request fits the ASP.Net pipeline; for example if the request is for a Controller or WebPage, Session is available. However if it's for an image, css file, etc, in most configurations Session is not available and doesn't even return null - just attempting to access it gets you an HttpException.

Comment: I know this answer is very old, but i searched for the same answer. i found some additional information:

Application_AcquireRequestState is the right place to get the session before the request is executed by the handler. if you want to know, if a session is available then check Context.Session for null. this will not raise the exception and after you know, there is a session you can use the variable Session to access it.

Comment: I ran into a problem where in Application_AcquireRequestState Session was still null. A session is only started when the Handler for the request implements IRequiresSessionState. If you can not change the handler but still need a session you can call 'Context.SetSessionStateBehavior(SessionStateBehavior.Required);'  in the Application_BeginRequest to force the generation of a session.

Answer (score 3):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.postacquirerequeststate.aspx) casually mentions that the session state is acquired during Application_PostAcquireRequestState event. I wish it was restated at the [Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470252.aspx) page.

The latest you can access session state is in Application_PostRequestHandlerExecute, as it is saved by SessionStateModule during the next event [Application_ReleaseRequestState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.releaserequeststate.aspx).

Comment: AcquireRequestState also has it available; using PostAcquireRequestState doesn't prevent Session from throwing an exception for requests for images, css files, etc.

Answer (score -3):

You need to use `BeginRequest` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.beginrequest.aspx) as it is the first event fired on the `HttpApplication` object (which the Global.asax inherits).

You'll see more about the ASP.NET Application Lifecycle here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx (this is for IIS 5 & IIS 6).

Comment: It might be the first _event_ fired on the HttpApplication object, but has the session be deserialised, by then?

Comment: According to the lifecycle the HttpContext has been created, which HttpSessionState is a property of

Comment: apparently this Answer is incorrect according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704940/when-is-the-earliest-i-can-access-session-in-the-asp-net-mvc-page-lifecycle

Comment: This answer does not work. Use the one provided by @ddc0660 instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/765054/whens-the-earliest-i-can-access-some-session-data-in-global-asax/1710257#1710257

Answer (score -4):

According to [link text](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-5771721.html), the earliest events in global.asax that you can access session objects is when global.asax fires Session_Start event

> **Session__Start**: Fired when a new user visits the application Web site.
>   **Session__End**: Fired when a user's session times out, ends, or they leave the application Web site

Comment: Those will only fire the first time someone visits a site, not during every request